# Run OS installed on external drive in windows

Tags: operating-system, external, hard-drive

I have an external hard drive connected to my computer via USB cable with Linux OS installed on it.
Is there a way that i can run this Linux while using Windows?
Like in virtual machine or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but you'll need to download a good enough emulator not small ones such as Bochs.Then configure the settings of the emulator such that it boots up the USB drive.Let me know which emulator you'd be using and I will help you setup if I know.

Comment: I am not familiar to such emulators. Is there a recommended one ?

Comment: I have VirtualBox and VMWare workstation. Where can i find instructions to configure it?

Comment: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-a-usb-flash-drive-in-virtualbox/ - You may refer this link on how to boot from USB using VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You'll need to download Oracle VM VirtualBox and use that. Its very easy to use. Just after you set up the Virtual machine you'll need to tell it to boot from usb.